# Tell me SQL Server Full-Text searcher is crazy, not me

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

i have some customers with a particular address that the user is searching for:

> 123 generic way

There are 5 rows in the database that match:

```
ResidentialAddress1
=============================
123 GENERIC WAY
123 GENERIC WAY
123 GENERIC WAY
123 GENERIC WAY
123 GENERIC WAY
```

---

i run a FT query to look for these rows. i'll show you each step as i add more criteria to the search:

```
SELECT ResidentialAddress1 FROM Patrons
WHERE CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"123*"')

ResidentialAddress1
=========================
123 MAPLE STREET
12345 TEST
123 MINE STREET
123 GENERIC WAY
123 FAKE STREET
...

(30 row(s) affected)
```

Okay, so far so good, now adding the word "*generic*":

```
SELECT ResidentialAddress1 FROM Patrons
WHERE  CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"123*"')
AND CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"generic*"')

ResidentialAddress1
=============================
123 GENERIC WAY
123 GENERIC WAY
123 GENERIC WAY
123 GENERIC WAY
123 GENERIC WAY

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Excellent. And now i'l add the final keyword that the user wants to make sure exists:

```
SELECT ResidentialAddress1 FROM Patrons
WHERE  CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"123*"')
AND CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"generic*"')
AND CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"way*"')


ResidentialAddress1            
------------------------------ 

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Huh? No rows? What if i query for just "way*":

```
SELECT ResidentialAddress1 FROM Patrons
WHERE CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"way*"')

ResidentialAddress1            
------------------------------ 

(0 row(s) affected)
```

At first i thought that perhaps it's because of the `*`, and it's requiring that the root `way` have more characters after it. But that's not true:

- Searching for "123*" matches "123"
- Searching for "generic*" matches "generic"
- Books online says, **The asterisk matches zero, one, or more characters**

What if i remove the `*` just for s&g:

```
SELECT ResidentialAddress1 FROM Patrons
WHERE CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"way"')

Server: Msg 7619, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A clause of the query contained only ignored words.
```

---

So one might think that you are just not allowed to even *search* for `way`, either alone, or as a root. But this isn't true either:

```
SELECT * FROM Patrons
WHERE CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"way*"')

AccountNumber FirstName Lastname
------------- --------- --------
33589         JOHN      WAYNE
```

---

So sum up, the user is searching for rows that contain all the words:

> 123 generic way

Which i, correctly, translate into the `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM Patrons
WHERE CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"123*"')
AND CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"generic*"')
AND CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"way*"')
```

which returns no rows. Tell me this just isn't going to work, that it's not my fault, and SQL Server is crazy.

**Note:** i've emptied the FT index and rebuilt it.

### Update One

```
SELECT Lastname, ResidentialAddress1 FROM Patrons
WHERE CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"gen*"')

Lastname                  ResidentialAddress1            
------------------------- ------------------------------ 
SAVE                      123 GENERIC WAY
Genders                   
SAVE                      123 GENERIC WAY
Patron                    123 GENERIC WAY
SAVE                      123 GENERIC WAY
SAVE                      234 GENERIC WAY
SAVE                      123 GENERIC WAY

(7 row(s) affected)
```

### Update Two

Pretending the user typed in:

> 123 generic wa

```
SELECT ResidentialAddress1 FROM Patrons
WHERE  CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"123*"')
AND CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"generic*"')
AND CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"wa*"')

ResidentialAddress1            
------------------------------ 

(0 row(s) affected)
```

The real problem is that the user is typing in something perfectly valid, and they would expect to see what any human being would expect to see.

---

### Update Three

Someone asked for all this, it's not my fault!:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patrons] (
    [PatronGUID]  uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL ,
    [AccountNumber] [bigint] NULL ,
    [FirstName] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [MiddleInitial] [varchar] (1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Lastname] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [EyeColor] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [HairColor] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Gender] [varchar] (1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Birthday] [datetime] NULL ,
    [Height] [int] NULL ,
    [Weight] [int] NULL ,
    [FacialHair] [tinyint] NULL ,
    [Nationality] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [IdentifyingMarks] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [DriversLicenseNumber] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [DriversLicenseRegion] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [DriversLicenseCountry] [varchar] (2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [DriversLicenseExpires] [datetime] NULL ,
    [DriversLicenseDateVerified] [datetime] NULL ,
    [PassportNumber] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PassportRegion] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PassportCountry] [varchar] (2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PassportExpires] [datetime] NULL ,
    [PassportDateVerified] [datetime] NULL ,
    [OtherIdentificationNumber] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [OtherIdentificationRegion] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [OtherIdentificationCountry] [varchar] (2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [OtherIdentificationType] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [OtherIdentificationExpires] [datetime] NULL ,
    [OtherIdentificationDateVerified] [datetime] NULL ,
    [ResidentialAddress1] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ResidentialAddress2] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ResidentialAddress3] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ResidentialCity] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ResidentialZipCode] [varchar] (15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ResidentialRegion] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ResidentialCountry] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ResidentialPhoneNumber] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [CountryOfResidence] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessAddress1] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessAddress2] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessAddress3] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessCity] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessRegion] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessZipCode] [varchar] (15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessCountry] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessName] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [BusinessPhone] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PositionWithFirm] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [EmployerTelephone] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [MemberCardType] [varchar] (1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PlayerStatusCode] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [AccountType] [varchar] (1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [AccountStatus1] [varchar] (1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [AccountStatus2] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [IsVIPExchangeRate] [tinyint] NULL ,
    [ChangedUserGUID_Depricated] [uniqueidentifier] NULL ,
    [ChangedUser] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ChangedDate] [datetime] NULL ,
    [ChangedWorkstation] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PendingUpdates_Depricated] [varchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Patrons] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_Patrons_PatronGUID] DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [PatronGUID],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Patrons] PRIMARY KEY  NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [PatronGUID]
    ) WITH  FILLFACTOR = 90  ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

if (select DATABASEPROPERTY(DB_NAME(), N'IsFullTextEnabled')) <> 1 
exec sp_fulltext_database N'enable' 

GO

if not exists (select * from dbo.sysfulltextcatalogs where name = N'TheFullTextCatalog')
exec sp_fulltext_catalog N'TheFullTextCatalog', N'create' 

GO

exec sp_fulltext_table N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'create', N'TheFullTextCatalog', N'PK_Patrons'
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'FirstName', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'MiddleInitial', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'Lastname', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'EyeColor', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'IdentifyingMarks', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'ResidentialAddress1', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'ResidentialAddress2', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'ResidentialAddress3', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'ResidentialCity', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'ResidentialZipCode', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'ResidentialRegion', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'ResidentialCountry', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'ResidentialPhoneNumber', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_column N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'CountryOfResidence', N'add', 1033  
GO

exec sp_fulltext_table N'[dbo].[Patrons]', N'activate'  
GO
```

Here's the screenshots for the guy who didn't believe me:

The query that should work but doesn't:

[image]

The query that works, but isn't useful:

[image]

The query that works, but isn't useful, with the proof content:

[image]

---

### Update Four

The query **cannot** be written as

```
CONTAINS(Patrons.*, 'words...')
```

Since there are items not logically or physically covered by the FT index. e.g. the user queries 
for:

> 6/4/2010 ian boyd 619

Presents four keywords:

- 6/4/2010
- ian
- boyd
- 619

This means they want all the conditions to hold true, with pseudo-code being:

```
WHERE 6/4/2010 is in the row
AND ian is in the row
AND boyd is in the row
AND 619 is in the row
```

Which is translated into a partial query of:

```
WHERE --Keyword 1: 6/4/2010
(
   ((ChangedDate >= '20100604') AND (ChangedDate < '20100605'))
   OR 
   ((LastTransactionDate >= '20100604') AND (LastTransactionDate < '20100605'))
   OR 
   (CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"6/4/2010*"')
)
AND --Keyword 2: ian
(
    CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"ian*"')
)
AND --Keyword 3: boyd
(
    CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"boyd*"')
)
AND --Keyword 4: 619
(
    (AccountNumber IN (SELECT CAST(619 AS bigint)))
    OR
    (CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"619*"'))
)
```

One of the answerers was looking at the simplified example presented in the original question;  not the real world. To say that it is **incorrect** to have multiple `AND` clauses is nieve.

Comment: SQL Server Full-Text searcher is crazy, not you! ;-)

Comment: What a fantastic question. How this has only received 2 upvotes is beyond me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is telling you that "way" is a stopword, which means it's ignored and not indexed.  That's why you can find "wayne" but not "way".

So, no, it's not crazy and neither are you.  There's just a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: What do you suggest? ie. How do i tell SQL Server to either search for  way when it can search for way, but not search for way when it can't search for way.

Comment: @Ardman Tried "wa*", results added to question. Doesn't work.

Comment: @Ian: I upvoted two answers that had more detail, so try those.  The short answer is that you need to remove "way" from your stop list and reindex.

Comment: /facepalm  i wish there was **any** other solution, than the one requiring hand-editing of text files on machines i don't have access to. In the end the solution might have to involve turning `CONTAINS(table.*)` into a few dozen `LIKE` clauses...

Comment: @Ian: In my experience, projects that start off using the FT search capabilities of a database tend to end up offloading that aspect to engines such as Lucene and DTSearch, precisely because relational databases are limited and frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

You probably used the system stoplist when you created the FT index.  The word `way` happens to be in there.  You can see it with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords
WHERE stopword = 'way'
AND language_id = 1033
```

You can turn off the stoplist or create a custom one, but a better solution would be to write the query properly; don't use multiple `WHERE CONTAINS` clauses, combine them into one.  Otherwise SQL Server might not be able to use the FT index as effectively.

Your query should look like this instead:

```
SELECT ResidentialAddress1 FROM Patrons
WHERE  CONTAINS(Patrons.ResidentialAddress1, '"123*" AND "generic*" AND "way*"')
```

If you do it this way, the stop word simply gets ignored; it'll still return all of the same results it would have returned if you hadn't included the term `way*`.

---

Edit: Just noticed that you tagged this `sql-server-2000`, so the first query might not work.  In SQL 2000, they are "noise words" and I believe that the configuration is global, you don't have individual stoplists.  Nevertheless, you'll still get results if you write a single `WHERE CONTAINS` clause instead of several.

To edit the noise words in SQL Server 2000, you have to edit the language-specific file in the SQL Server `FTDATA` configuration folder.  More details are here: [SQL Server Full Text Search Noise Words and Thesaurus Configurations](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1491).

Comment: Running `SELECT * FROM Patrons WHERE CONTAINS(Patrons.*, '"123*" AND "generic*" AND "way*"')` returns no rows. And yes: 2000, noisewords, not queryable.

Comment: @Ian: That doesn't seem right at all.  Can we get a repro including the table schema and FT DDL?

Comment: That's a hellavalotta ddl, and scripts, for nobody to use.

Comment: Also writing the query as a single Contains, as they are fields no covered by the FT index (e.g. tinyint) that require a separate clause.  So the solution checking for the presence of **all** keywords is correct.

Comment: @Ian: It shouldn't be a "hellavalotta" - if you're not able to reproduce it on a small scale then something else is wrong.  And yeah, obviously if you're looking up numeric values in other fields then you have to write `AND` conditions, but all of the fulltext criteria should be in a single search string.  Writing several `CONTAINS` clauses *isn't* correct unless you need to check different fields for *each*.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

You want to try the [Transform Noise Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187914.aspx)  option **(SQL 2008)**.

Turning this off, should stop word removal.

### example:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

**Edit 1:**

Hopefully there may be something similar for older versions of MS SQL?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/stop-me-if-you-think-youve-seen-this-word-before.html

In that post, Jeff mentions you can turn them off.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it requires more than three alphabet characters. Try another three letter word, like `gen*`.

Comment: "gen*" works, which makes sense, since "123*" also works. Will add to question anyway