# MS SQL Fulltext Search for Roman Numerals

Tags: .net, sql-server, full-text-search

My query is "Rocky IV" but I also want rocky 4 to appear.  I set up this on my thesaurus file,
         
            <sub>4</sub>
            <sub>iv</sub>

and use formsof thesaurus in my query.  I am using CONTAINSTABLE.

But a seemingly random set of all titles that contain the word rocky come back.  Rocky i, Rocky and Bullwinkle, etc.  Actual Rocky IV and rocky 4 are somewhere in the middle if I sort by rank.

Is the number too short?  How can I improve my search results to put rocky iv and rocky 4 at the top?

Comment: Not sure about the behavior but I would thesaurus both ways 4 IV and IV 4.

Answer (score 0):

Turned off stopwords with
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON MyTable SET STOPLIST = OFF

Works fine now.
Relevant links:
[Tell me SQL Server Full-Text searcher is crazy, not me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966369/tell-me-sql-server-full-text-searcher-is-crazy-not-me)

[Make SQL Server index small numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562/make-sql-server-index-small-numbers)